# FIlter an array based an another array string item

Tags: arrays, swift

I know my question is very simple and so sorry for asking it

I have two arrays for countries and in each of two array there are two object

```
array1[0].name = "US"

arrary1[0].code = "1"
```

In this array, all the countries are listes

but in the another array I have a few country.

```
 array2[0].countryName = "US"

 arrary2[0].countryCode = "1"
```

I want to filter the first array that only shows the country that are in the second array

```
 let counrtyInfos = array1.filter{ $0.name == array2.first?.countryName}
```

In this code, it's only take the first index value, I don't know how to apply this filter to all of the second array.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
let array2Names = array2.compactMap({ $0.name })
let counrtyInfos = array1.filter({ array2Names.contains($0.name) })!
```

Comment: You can use `contains(where:)` instead so you don't have to create the interim array.

Comment: Thank you soo much